# Is there any way to disable multi select option in Lightning-dual-list box?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, lightning-design-system

I wanted to select only one option at a time in Lightning-dual-list box.

Answer (score 2):

Use `max="1"` property.

> Maximum number of options allowed in the selected options listbox.

```html
<lightning-dual-listbox 
    max="1"
></lightning-dual-listbox>
```

Resources:

- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-dual-listbox/specification

Comment: max = 1, will only allow me to select one option. I want more than one option to be selected, but one each time. I select one option and push it to the selected box, and select another option and push it to the selected list.